# Playing Sound In Hidden Tag

Tags: html, audio

I am trying to set sound on web page.

I found this code. It is working code when the `div` is visible but I want to be hidden and working. In this case it is not working because it is hidden with `style` attribute. How to make it not visible and playing sound at the same time ?

```
<div style="display:none">
   <embed src="sound.mp3"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: You should look into the HTML 5 `audio` element.

Comment: I tried with this and it is working in hidden mode.Good work. <audio autoplay="autoplay" hidden="hidden">
            <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"">
        </audio>

Comment: I don't know why everyone is assuming that this will be used for something nefarious. You could dynamically play a sound based on user input on a website, which is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 20):

I agree with the sentiment in the comments above — this **can** be pretty annoying. We can only hope you give the user the option to turn the music off.

However...

```css
audio { display:none;}
```

```html
<audio autoplay="true" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg">
```

The css hides the `audio` element, and the `autoplay="true"` plays it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to attach an audio which should autoplay and will be hidden.
It's very simple. Just a few lines of HTML and CSS. Check this out!!
   Here is the piece of code I used within the body.

```
<div id="player">
    <audio controls autoplay hidden>
     <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                unsupported !! 
    </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<audio autoplay>
<source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`

It removes the auto play bar but still plays the music. Invisible sounds!

Answer (score 1):

That's how I achieved it, which is not visible (*HORRIBLE SOUND....*)

```
<!-- horrible is your mp3 file name any other supported format.-->
<audio controls autoplay hidden="" src="horrible.mp3" type ="audio/mp3"">your browser does not support Html5</audio>
```

Comment: Why provide controls if the audio player is hiden?

Answer (score 1):

```css
audio { display:none;}
```

```html
<audio autoplay="true" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope people would allow them to turn things such as music off, as for button clicks, Sometimes, those are pretty cool. 
Use the

`<audio controls autoplay hidden="hidden">
   <source src="*file here*" type="*file extension (.mp3 .ogg etc.)*">
   <!--This displays an error to users that don't have it supported-->
   Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>`

As you can see, I don't like to repeat myself much, But I decided with the `hidden` tag.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="mp3/Fans-Mi-tooXclusive_com.mp3" controls autoplay loop onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()">
```

This auto-plays, hides the music and reduces the music even if system volume is high to avoid noise. Place this in script:

```
<script>
    function setHalfVolume() {
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio");
        myAudio.volume = 0.2;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, what I do is put the normal audio tag, and then put `autoplay="true"` and  I don't add: controls ="true" and that usually works for me

I put this in a snippet and also made a jsfiddel [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Foxygaming9978/0teazcs5/)

Hope this helps :)

```html
<audio autoplay="true" 
src="https://res.cloudinary.com/foxyplays989/video/upload/v1558369838/LetsGo.mp3"> 
</audio>
```