# Audio file does not play if it's hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert an audio file in html but it doesn't play if I set it to hidden.

```
<audio src="file/example.ogg" autoplay="true" hidden="true" loop="true" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing Sound In Hidden Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533636/playing-sound-in-hidden-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to hide the audio tag using CSS `display` instead of `hidden` attribute:

```
<audio src="file/example.ogg" autoplay="true" loop="true" />
```

```css
audio {
    display: none;
}
```

**Note:** Audio and Video tags can played automatically only when they are muted. (beacause of user privacy)

```html
<audio src="file/example.ogg" autoplay="true" hidden="true" loop="true" muted="true" />
```