# Disable background music from being controlled

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an `audio` HTML element with background music for a game:

```html
<audio class="music" src="..." loop></audio>
```

Then I have a JS event listener that starts playing it with `.play()` on user interaction. The problem is, I noticed that on loading the page, I can control the music from the OS/browser's media controls.

I can control it from Chrome:

[image]

And my macOS media controls also show up:

[image]

How can I "hide" this from the browser so that it doesn't show up like this?

Comment: Does adding `controls controlsList="nodownload"` to `<audio />` fix it?

Comment: Does this post helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533636/playing-sound-in-hidden-tag

Comment: @clxrity It doesn't seem to.

Comment: @indyteo Sorry, it doesn't. That's a different issue (and for the record, I tried some of the answers to that question and they didn't work).

Comment: Them I'm unsure if you can control the appearance of this, unfortunately... :/

Comment: I'm quite sure it's possible because I've seen many sites where this is the case.

Comment: Can you please give us one website that do it? Just to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AudioContext` and load an audio track using [`decodeAudioData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) to play it.

Here is a sample implementation:

```js
let audioCtx = null;

async function init_sound() {
  const soundfile = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/5/56/Piano_Sonata_N%C2%B0_1_-_1._Allegro_%28Beethoven%2C_Schnabel%29.ogg/Piano_Sonata_N%C2%B0_1_-_1._Allegro_%28Beethoven%2C_Schnabel%29.ogg.mp3";

  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  const resp = await fetch(soundfile);
  const buf = await resp.arrayBuffer();
  const audio = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buf);
  const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audio;
  source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  source.start();
}

function play() {
  if (!audioCtx) {
    init_sound();
    return;
  };
  audioCtx.resume();
}

function pause() {
  audioCtx.suspend();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="play" value="Play" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause" onclick="pause()">
```

Comment: Thanks! I was afriad the bounty would go to waste but this worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- see i have made a variable name status to check if i paused the audio or some other source paused if . if i paused it then do nothing if it'spaused due to other source then start playing it i have added 1 second interval you can decrease it it's worked perfectely fine 
this method worked perfectly fine with audio tag but I have added onother thing which i found on stack overflow its in 2nd script tag 
Thanks 
 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>

    let status = 0 ;
      setInterval(func3,1000)
    function func() {    
       a.play();
       console.log(status)
        status = 1;
        console.log(status)
    }

    function func1() {
        a.pause();
        console.log(status)
        status = 0;
        console.log(status)
    }
    function func3() {
        console.log("i am trying my best")
       if (status == 1){
        if (a.paused){
            a.play();
        }
       }
       if (status ==0 ) {
         if(!a.paused){
            a.pause();
         }
       } 
    }
   console.log(status);
    </script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div title="jha">i am abhishek jha </div>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="func()" >play</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="func1()" >pause</button>
    <audio class="music" src="badliar.mp" loop preload="auto">abhi</audio>

    <script>
        
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({});
    const a = new Audio("./badliar.mp3");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal isn't to prevent them from pausing it, but to hide it altogether. This would probably just be confusing if someone tried to use it.

Comment: Also, I tried your `navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({});` which sounded like it would work but it didn't, unfortunately.

Comment: let status = 0 ;
      setInterval(func3,1000)
    function func() {    
       a.play();
       console.log(status)
        status = 1;
        console.log(status)
    }
this is the main code that we are saying if he or she has paused music using website or using chrome

Comment: navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({}) :: its just replacment of html tag nothing more real implementation is in above code

Answer (score 0):

```
 instruction = "this one is best this one work as you want try it "

documentatio = "http://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="waveform"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
<script>
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});
wavesurfer.load('./badliar.mp3');
wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any external libraries.